# ASP.NET and JQuery - Popup for dropdownlist selected value

Tags: asp.net, jquery, drop-down-menu

What I'm looking to do is popup an "are you sure" confirmation box if the newly selected value of a dropdownlist is a certain value before I submit the form.

```
<select name="ListSearchType" id="ListSearchType">
    <option value="C">Closed</option>
    <option value="O">Open</option>
    <option value="P">Pending</option>
</select>
```

So if I had the dropdownlist like above with autopostback enabled, I'd want to popup a confirmation box if the user select 'Closed' before the form is submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#ListSearchType").onchange(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "C") {
       var confirmed = confirm("Are you sure ?");
       if (!confirmed) {
          return false;
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One way that comes to my mind is instead of setting the `autopostback` option = true, you could manage the client event `change` with jquery.

Within the `change` handler you would check the selected option and perform a manual postback according values / user confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

**On Form Submit Solution:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#yourFormID").submit(function () {
    if ($("#ListSearchType").val() == "C")) {
      if (!confirm("ARe you sure?")) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  });
});
```

**On Change Of Field Solution**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#ListSearchType").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "C")) {
          if (!confirm("ARe you sure?")) {
             //Do something..disable submit, revert to original value.
          }
        }
      });
    });
```